# finding the correct interpolation accuracy

Tags: interpolation

Ciao, 
I need to interpolate this data:

```
{{800.00000000000000, 4.2872055064128674*10^-14},  
 {800.33333333333326, 2.4243226146602945*10^-14},
 {800.66666666666663, 4.2221723933087801*10^-15}, 
 {801.00000000000000, -6.0951356556178097*10^-15}, 
 {801.33333333333326, -1.7335678567063522*10^-15},
 {801.66666666666663, 1.2585978296175717*10^-14},
 {802.00000000000000,  2.7421070601669856*10^-14}}
```

I have tried with the function `Interpolation` and Polynomial interpolation. However if I used just order 1 or 2 the results I get is not correct. In fact I have real data that I use as a comparison of my goodness of the interpolation function. Instead if I go to order 6 or higher the situation seems to get better. For what I know if you increase the order of interpolation you should lose the accuracy and your polynomial can oscillate. Therefore I do not really understand why if I go to bigger order I get more precise results.

Anyone has a suggestion to use the correct interpolation?

Someone told me I should use lagrangian interpolation order 31.

Comment: With only seven data points, I don't think you can get an order-31 interpolant.  --  The general rules of thumb you discuss have exceptions.  There are too many details missing to comment further.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to quickly compare the data points you have to the interpolation results using different interpolation orders:

```
pts = {{800.00000000000000, 4.2872055064128674*10^-14}, 
       {800.33333333333326, 2.4243226146602945*10^-14}, 
       {800.66666666666663, 4.2221723933087801*10^-15}, 
       {801.00000000000000, -6.0951356556178097*10^-15}, 
       {801.33333333333326, -1.7335678567063522*10^-15}, 
       {801.66666666666663, 1.2585978296175717*10^-14}, 
       {802.00000000000000, 2.7421070601669856*10^-14}}; 

Manipulate[
  Plot[
    Interpolation[pts, InterpolationOrder -> n][x], {x, 800, 802},
    Epilog -> Point[pts]
  ],
  {n, 1, Length[pts] - 1, 1}
]
```

[image: manipulate output with plot]

As you can see, already at an interpolation order of 3, interpolation results in a smooth curve that of course goes through your points.

You should better define your requirements for us to see what exactly you find wrong with these results. If you are trying to do extrapolation, i.e. calculate function values for values of the independent variable outside of the range covered by your existing points, you should always proceed with great caution.